# Image stretches to 100% while loading when server-side rendering

Tags: css, angular, responsive-design, angular-material, angular-universal

I have the following code which uses Angular Material to make my image responsive:

```
<picture [ngStyle.xs]="{'width': '100%'}" [ngStyle.gt-xs]="{'width': '448px', 'height': '60px'}">
  <source srcset="/assets/images/logo-text-lg.webp" type="image/webp" [ngStyle.xs]="{'width': '100%'}" [ngStyle.gt-xs]="{'width': '448px', 'height': '60px'}">
  <source srcset="/assets/images/logo-text-lg.png" type="image/png" [ngStyle.xs]="{'width': '100%'}" [ngStyle.gt-xs]="{'width': '448px', 'height': '60px'}">
  <img src="/assets/images/logo-text-lg.png" alt="TechScore" [ngStyle.xs]="{'width': '100%'}" [ngStyle.gt-xs]="{'width': '448px', 'height': '60px'}">
</picture>
```

The goal is to have it exactly 448x60 unless it is on an extra small screen. Then it should be 100% of the page width. This works except that, since I implemented server-side rendering via Angular Universal, I get a flash of the image at 100% even on larger screens.

[image: stretched image]

[image: image once loaded]

If I look at the source (with caching disabled) I can see that the markup coming from the server includes `style="width: 100%"` which means that the server-side rendered version thinks that the screen is extra small.

How can I let Angular Universal known what the screen resolution is and how do I pass that information on to Angular Material and override what it *thinks* is the resolution so that it chooses the correct width?

**Update**

I thought I was onto something by detecting if it was a mobile browser via the user-agent string and then setting the default breakpoints as described here: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Using-SSR-with-Flex-Layout

```
FlexLayoutModule.withConfig({ssrObserveBreakpoints: [isMobile() ? 'xs' : 'md']})
```

but I must be doing it wrong because I'm not seeing any effect.

Comment: I don't think things from Angular are available while your page is served through SSR. Later, when the hydration happens, all of ng rules kick in and you get things as expected. I'll suggest, doing this through CSS that can load with SSR too and looking at the requirement, it doesn't look like a lot

Comment: I agree with Praveen, I think you are going to have to use css for this. Media queries are an option, you may also be able to use `max-width` although it's difficult to be more specific without a reproducible snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider using CSS media queries to handle the responsive styling of the images. Then no hardcoded inline styles will be sent to the client. The browser will determine how to initially render the images. You won't have to wait for your JavaScript to execute (flash!) before the appropriate styles are applied.

Here's an example:

```
<picture class="my-picture">
  <source srcset="/assets/images/logo-text-lg.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="/assets/images/logo-text-lg.png" type="image/png" >
  <img src="/assets/images/logo-text-lg.png" alt="TechScore">
</picture>
```

```css
.my-picture, .my-picture img, .my-picture source {
  width: 448px;
  height: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  .my-picture, .my-picture img, .my-picture source {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tom from MN? Did we work together? I was hoping for a solution that would apply everywhere in the site that media breakpoints are used, but if I can't figure that out, this will at least work for that particular image. Thanks.

Comment: Ha! Hey, Adam. What a crazy coincidence! You don't have to give me the sympathy vote since you know me IRL. Someone may pipe in with a nice way to get the SSR to shape up. Although, if you're aggressively caching the output of the SSR assets, it might be difficult to get variability based on client information.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Your solution works great for the image, but I'm going to add a bounty to see if I can learn how to get the breakpoints working for content throughout the site.

Comment: Fair enough. Let's see what folks say.

Answer (score 0):

Please try CSS below this will maintain the ratio.

```
 .img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

FlexLayout **does** [support server side rendering](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Using-SSR-with-Flex-Layout) with certain limitations.

I wouldn't attempt to use it without first reading this document

[Angular Flex Layout - Server Side Rendering](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fg04ihw42dJJHGd6fugdiBe39iJot8aErhiE7CjwfmQ/edit#)

Answer (score -1):

You can set a variable inside your Typescript that states if the screen is in mobile (by width) and then change the classes.

here's an example :

```js
isMobile = false;
ngOnInit() {
    if (window.screen.width <= 480) { // 768px portrait
      this.isMobile = true;
    }
}
```

then inside your template :

```html
<picture [ngClass.xs] = "isMobile">
 ...
</picture>
```

> Edit:

I saw you were looking to get the screen size into the server. There is no way for the server to get the screen size unless you send him this data, and save it. You can send the `window.screen.width` into the server when the client starts and then serves the specific user with the screen size you have.

Comment: If I sent it from the client, then there would be no point in doing server-side rendering because the client would've already been rendered. The question is how to do it via SSR on initial page load. I don't necessarily need the **exact** dimensions... the approach I started taking in the question with the `user-agent` string would be good enough if I could get it working.

Answer (score -2):

If You want to keep same size throughout the site. Than it may help you.

```
 <picture>
          <source srcset="/assets/images/logo-text-lg.webp" class="my-picture" type="image/webp">
          <source srcset="/assets/images/logo-text-lg.png" class="my-picture" type="image/png" >
          <img src="/assets/images/logo-text-lg.png" class="my-picture" alt="TechScore">
 </picture>

<style>
        .my-picture {
          width: 448px;
          height: 60px;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
          .my-picture {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
          }
        }

       @media only screen and (max-width : 667px) {
          .my-picture {
            width: 50%;
            height: auto;
          }
        }

       @media only screen and (min-width : 668px) {
          .my-picture {
            width: 448px;
           height: 60px;
          }
        }

</style>
```

You may change size according to your requirements.

Comment: This answer looks familiar.